# Parsing XML data and save it to temp table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to parse the below XML and return the results. The `Column` element will grow with different `DestinationColumnCode` attributes. So I need to make the script dynamic.

Result:

```
RowNumbers      Code                      Pay1_515
73123            5570, Industry1, 1       10
73124            5570, Industry2, 2       10
```

Sample XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CookedData>
     <RowNumbers>
        <rn v="73123" />
        <rn v="73124" />
    </RowNumbers>
     <Column DestinationColumnCode="Code">
        <r v="5570, Industry1, 1" />
        <r v="5570, Industry2, 2" />
    </Column>
    <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_515">
       <r v="10" />
        <r v="10" />
    </Column>
    </CookedData>
```

Comment: Does it have to be pure t-sql, or can you use a programming language as well?

Comment: @ZoharPeled- it should be a pure t-sql

Comment: This specific XML, or any number of rows, in this structure? Is a stored procedure allowed?

Comment: Yes any number of rows for example another row is <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_60">
       <r v="1" />
        <r v="1" />
    </Column>
the another row is <Column DestinationColumnCode="Scope_5">
       <r v="5" />
        <r v="10" />
    </Column>

Comment: @Turophile- Yes actually this is a stored procedure, however this part is a more tricky that is why I am asking it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With dynamic number of columns in the output you need to build a query dynamically.

But first we need to figure out what that query would look like because once we go dynamic on this it will look a bit complicated.

Using this XML variable declaration:

```
declare @XML xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CookedData>
  <RowNumbers>
    <rn v="73123" />
    <rn v="73124" />
  </RowNumbers>
  <Column DestinationColumnCode="Code">
    <r v="5570, Industry1, 1" />
    <r v="5570, Industry2, 2" />
  </Column>
  <Column DestinationColumnCode="Pay1_515">
    <r v="10" />
    <r v="10" />
  </Column>
</CookedData>';
```

The query can look like this:

```
with C as
(
  select T.X.value('@v', 'int') as RowNumber,
         row_number() over(order by T.X) as Position
  from @XML.nodes('/CookedData/RowNumbers/rn') as T(X)
)
select C.RowNumber,
       @XML.value('(/CookedData/Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Code"]/r[sql:column("C.Position")]/@v)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Code,
       @XML.value('(/CookedData/Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "Pay1_515"]/r[sql:column("C.Position")]/@v)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Pay1_515
from C;
```

The tricky part with this query is to match the `RowNumbers` with the position of the `r` node in the `Column`nodes.

The CTE `C` Returns a list of `RowNumber` and the `Position` for each `RowNumber`. That position is used in the xPath expression `r[sql:column("C.Position")]` to get the `r` node for each `RowNumber`.

Now all that is left is to build and execute the above query dynamically using the column definitions in the XML.

That can be done by extracting each column definition and concatenating them back together using `for xml path('')`.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = '
with C as
(
  select T.X.value(''@v'', ''int'') as RowNumber,
         row_number() over(order by T.X) as Position
  from @XML.nodes(''/CookedData/RowNumbers/rn'') as T(X)
)
select C.RowNumber' + 
  (
  select ', 
       @XML.value(''(/CookedData/Column[@DestinationColumnCode = "'+T.Name+'"]/r[sql:column("C.Position")]/@v)[1]'', ''nvarchar(max)'') as '+quotename(T.Name)
  from (
       select T.X.value('@DestinationColumnCode', 'nvarchar(max)')
       from @XML.nodes('/CookedData/Column') as T(X)
       ) as T(Name)
  for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')+'
from C;';

--print @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XML xml', @XML;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17348)

<sub>Note: The technique using `row_number()` to get the position of nodes in a XML document relies on knowledge of the internal implementation of how SQL Server parses XML. The behaviour is not documented by Microsoft. Adam Machanic has blogged about it here: [Uniquely Identifying XML Nodes with DENSE_RANK](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/03/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense-rank.aspx)</sub>